# How can I wait until something is not null then run the function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So currently this function `highlight` gets called on the `ngOnInit` but the text that gets put into the `DOM` takes a second or so to be written into the `DOM`.

Therefore it is returning `null` when the function gets run and is expecting the text there. How can I get this function to run when `document.getElementById('scrollable')` does **NOT** `=== null`.

The only way I have got it to run so far has been with a timeout of `800ms` but that was not good because some people have slower internet than others so it would cause issues if the internet or computer takes longer to load the page.

I have tried a few different ways but none of them work. If anyone has any good advice please feel free to tell me.

```
highlight(words) {
      const high = document.getElementById('scrollable');
      const paragraph = high.innerHTML.split(' ');
   }
}
```

Currently using Angular 6.

HTML: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/fa78b5b25a73716e2c32045c6c6be1ff

TS: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/85950e0e84aad30a72d3b91faa7d6278

Comment: Could you give some more context - are you sure this is the best way to do that overall? Using the document API is usually not a great sign in Angular.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Currently I have on the `ngOnInit` functions which search the post I have clicked and gets the text and the special words. The text gets put into the page, and this function basically runs through the text and highlights the difficult words. Problem is this function runs before the text is inside the innerHTML so it throws the error. If I loaded the document and clicked this function it works because the text is loaded, same if I do a timeout function. But I wanted it to get run automatically. Sorry, I'm not the best at explaining.

Comment: I'm looking at your gists : stop using `document.getElementById`, `innerHTML`, `createElement` and such : Angular offers an abstraction for that and advises not to handle the DOM yourself. If you keep using vanillaJS, there's no point in using Angular. Also, consider using directives for those behaviors, it will be easier to use, both in your HTML and TS code.

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you for the advice, I am only new to all this. I will take your advice and try to implement it. If you could give any examples it would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Well given the size of your code and the fact that it's basic Angular code, I won't give you examples, but you can on [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) and look for `ViewChild`, `interpolation`, `renderer2` (or `Ivy` in Angular 6), which are all made for what you are tryign to achieve. I know that when you start a new framework, the quantity of code to learn is overwhelming, but you should put yourself into it, because you will gain a lot of time once you understand all that. And if you have a question, we're still here !

Comment: Will do, thank you for your kind words and motivation. Graduated last week hehe @trichetriche hard work will eventually get me there thanks. I will read the documentation but I am worried I will struggle with changing it over at this stage.

Comment: @Andrew well congratulations then ! And since you are a new developer, let me welcome to the wonderful world of programming, where you spend 10% of your time creating, 40% of your time testing, and 50% of your time rewriting your old code !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177031/discussion-between-andrew-and-trichetriche).

Comment: Following our discussion yesterday, I have made [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kb8742?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhard-word-highlight.directive.ts) to show you one of the many ways of handling the highlighting of hard words in a paragraph. The blite is all commented to explain to you how and why I'm doing everything I do. Feel free to check the documentation each time you don't get something, and if you have any questions on it, feel free to ask me there !

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [Angular Component Life Cycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). You should use `AfterViewInit` hook to make sure your view is initialized.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyOwnComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() { // Here your view is checked and initialized.
    this.highlight();
  }

  highlight(words) {
    const high = document.getElementById('scrollable');
    const paragraph = high.innerHTML.split(' ');
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I tested this a couple of weeks ago but had no luck with this, I was hoping this would work to be honest. But the innerHTML is still null when it gets run.

Comment: How does your page gets filled? Through an API call or static content? You should call this `highlight` function when you're data is ready.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/fa78b5b25a73716e2c32045c6c6be1ff That's the gist for my HTML, I will create one for my component. I have shortened it down so you can see exactly what I'm doing. @Jonathan Hamel

Comment: My ts: https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/85950e0e84aad30a72d3b91faa7d6278